# Css overlay working on localhost but not server

Tags: css

I did an overlay on an image using a text which is actually working on my localhost very well, but after I deploy my web app to a live server the overlay on image refuse to work. help please. 
Below is my code

```
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center ">
    <div class="rounded border m-1 p-1" id="box">
     <a href="<?php echo URL?>onlineMarket" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <div class="sitecolor2" >
            <img src="<?php echo URL?>images/online-market'.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="pt-5" id="overlay">Online Market</div>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    #box {
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
    }

    #box>a{
         color: white; 
    }

    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    /*    background-color: rgba(187, 213, 120, 0.24);*/
    }
```

This is what i have in my local server http://prntscr.com/hkaqwv
while this is what its showing me after deploying to live server http://prntscr.com/hkas1j

Comment: It works - https://jsfiddle.net/q6wcr8sf/. There is no reason why it should work on localhost and not on server, CSS is interpreted in browser, not on server.

Comment: Please explain what you've already tried in your question. Otherwise you'll probably get fewer useful answers than hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

it finally worked. i cleared my browser cache. cos it was using the old css and not the updated one. thanks